# Динамически формируемая последовательность действий

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть ограниченный список возможных событий (действий)
Когда и в какой последовательности они произойдут заранее не известно.
У события есть некое время исполнения (3 секунды)
Надо сделать так чтобы в случае если два или более события произошли одновременно (или в промежутке времени менее 3 секунд) то следующее событие дожидалось бы исполнения предыдущего, формируя условную очередь.

Т.е. Если за промежуток менее 3 сек произошли события 1,3, и 7 то нужно что бы
начало исполняться событие 1 
ждём 3 сек
событие 3
ждём 3 сек
событие 7

Как это вообще можно сделать?
Coroutine не подходят тк как я понял после инициализации корутина "блокируется" и новые переменные уже получить не может ( те если мы инициализировали coroutine с событиями 1 и 3  а потом (после инициализации но до исполнения) произошло событие 7  -то это самое событие 7 потеряется или запустит новую корутину поверх уже работающей)

Всё что мне приходит в голову это иметь в Update() динамически очищаемый Array 
или List куда будут записываться действия и откуда каждые 3 сек они будут браться на исполнение...
Но это как-то очень громоздко и в Update() лезть не хотелось бы.

Можно ли реализовать эту задачу как то проще?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы реализовал это на подобие патерна `Observer`. Сделал общий класс который помнит кому нужно реагировать на события, и сделал методы для подписки на события, вызова события и возврата после завершения события. Таким образом вы делаете список событий по мере их возникновения где регистрируете обработку событий из сторонних классов через подписку, а порядок исполнения запускаете только после того как объект обрабатывающий событие ответил что событие завершилось.
Таким образом ваши события будут обрабатываться независимо от Update и легко конфигурироваться. Я делал нечто подобное, но без ожидания по завершению событий.